# Rails 4 serve Facebook avatar over https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, https

On my ruby on rails app, following were a snippet for header to fetch logged-in user avatar:

```
<% if current_user.get_avatar_url.present? %>
                                    <img src="<%= current_user.get_avatar_url %>" width="40" height = "40" class="img-circle profile-nav"/>
                                <% else %>
                                    <img src="<%= asset_url('default-avatar.png') %>" width="40" height = "40" class="img-circle profile-nav"/>
                                <% end %>
```

And the `controller` code were:

```
def get_avatar_url
    ret = ''
    if self.profile.present? && self.profile.user_avatar.present?
        ret = self.profile.user_avatar.avatar.thumb.url
    end
    if ret.blank? && self.provider == 'facebook'
        ret = self.profile.avatar
    end
    ret = '/assets/default-avatar.png' if ret.blank?
    ret
end
```

Now when I inspect the page, I get something like this:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxx/picture?type=large" width="40" height="40" class="img-circle profile-nav">
```

Which now causing of Mixed content warning on console

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/#_=_' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/picture?type=large'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `OmniAuth`? The [configuration](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring) shows an option `secure_image_url=true` to load over https.